# How do I use RDMA in the kernel so that I can communicate with user-space RDMA?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, rdma, userspace

I have written a kernel module that needs to use RDMA to communicate with RDMA programs in remote user space. Some online open source implementations (such as INFINISWAP) are referred to, but there are problems that are difficult to determine and solve.
The process of kernel module RDMA mainly includes address resolution, initialization PD, CQ, QP, buffer, adding request to the receiving queue, connection and so on. At present, the execution appears to be successful in establishing the connection, but there are some error messages in the user space code. Specifically, the on_completion function will display the following prompt:

```
on_completion, wc->status is 11,opcode=0
on_completion, status is not IBV_WC_SUCCESS
```

Status 11 is IBV_WC_REM_OP_ERR.

I looked through a lot of sources and debugged the user-space code, but still couldn't solve the problem. The kernel module cannot be debugged at this time due to conditions. What is the cause of this problem and how can I solve it? Or where is the rdma demo of a simple kernel module?

Comment: What operation is returning that?
are you sure you have prepared appropriate MRs with correct access rights?
what nic provides rdma capability?